# Derivative of a Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, stieltjes-integral

Suppose we have smooth real functions $f,g$ such that the Riemann–Stieltjes integral $\int_0^t f(s) dg(s)$ is defined for all $t>0$ and is smooth as a function of $t$.

Is their an analytic formula for $\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(s) dg(s)$ in terms of $f$ and $g$ ?

Bonus: If so, is it also the case for the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral and the stochastic integral ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is smooth (indeed continuously differentiable) then the following identity holds
$$
\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm dg(s)=\int_0^tf(s)g'(s)\mathrm ds
$$
where the integral on the RHS is a Riemann integral. Then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (the integrand is certainly continuous)
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm dg(s)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^tf(s)g'(s)\mathrm ds=f(t)g'(t)
$$

Edit: The idea is as follows; if $0<x_0<\dots<x_n<t$ is a partition
$$
\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm d g(s)\approx\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_*)(g(x_{i})-g(x_{i-1}))
$$
for $x_{i-1}\leq x_*\leq x_{i}$but by the Mean value theorem 
$$
g(x_{i})-g(x_{i-1})=(x_i-x_{i-1})g'(c_i)
$$
for $x_{i-1}<c<x_{i}$. In the limit as $\sup_{i}|x_{i}-x_{i-1}|\to 0$, we have $c_i=x_*$ and the usual definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a reference or a proof for the identity ?

Comment: Yes, it should follow from the definition of the stieltjes integral and applying the mean value theorem to $g$ on each difference in the partition. I would guess this is in Rudin chapter 6 but do not have the book on me